# Is it possible to use the SODA tool as open source?

Tags: data, tools, data-engineering, etl, data-quality

I was reading about the SODA tool and was wondering if it was free to use. As far as I understand, it has a SODA library and a SODA core, but they are all just clients for connecting to a cloud server that comes at a price.

Tell me, is it possible to use SODA for free?

Answer (score 1):

Soda Core is completely free to use (as well as open-source), as indicated on the [documentation page](https://docs.soda.io/soda-core/overview-main.html):

> Soda Core is a free, open-source Python library and CLI tool that
> enables data engineers to test data quality. Accessible on along with
> its documentation, you can download the CLI tool or import the Python
> library to prepare checks for data quality.
>
> - Available for free
> - Compatible with basic SodaCL checks and configurations
> - Supports connections to 18+ data sources